# What is 「切れ」 in 切れかけの蛍光灯?

Tags: meaning, words

What is 「切れ」 as in 「切れかけの蛍光灯。」?

Comment: Your first topic was marked as a duplicate. The topic it was a duplicate of addressed both parts of this, what the first half and second half of 切れかけ is.

Comment: @existence You've just posted a new question. Every question here has to be organized so that it makes sense on its own, and you have to show your research effort. If you want a small clarification about your existing question, please use the comment section (*this* place).

Comment: just as the first answer said, 切れるhas a lot of meanings, I don't know which it is and I think it's a little weird  especially when I saw a very bright and  clear picture illustrated as 切れかけ。

Answer (score 3):

切れる has [a lot of meanings](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B), and in this context it means "to go out", "to burn out", etc. There is no physical filament which will burn out for a fluorescent lamp, but people still use 切れる. かけ is "half ～", "almost ～", etc. Therefore 切れかけの蛍光灯 refers to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92NQvRiI7xc).

Comment: i don’t think so, kireru do have the meaning of almost, half~ ect.. While kake is equal to almost~, here kireru doesn't mean almost, right? Or these two are the same in meaning. It should be something near a verb or an adj. that explain the characteristic of the lamp. So what exactly is kireru?

Comment: @Existence Please re-read my answer. I clearly said 切れる in this context means "to go out", "to burn out".

Comment: then what is a burned out lamp?

Comment: @Existence 「切れた電球」ですかね・・

Comment: @Existence For instance, 死んだ人 = dead person; 死にかけの人 = half-dead/dying person; 壊れたラジオ = broken radio; 壊れかけのラジオ = half-broken radio; 切れた蛍光灯 = broken/dead lump; 切れかけの蛍光灯 = half-broken (i.e., flickering) lump. Did I make myself clear?

Comment: it's better to make clear the meaning of  the word 切れ. don't you think?

Comment: @Chocolateそうですね！

Comment: @Existence What do you mean? The very first sentence of my answer clearly addressed that point, didn't it? But why do you believe 切れる itself has the meaning of "almost; half ～"? As far as I can recall, 切れる doesn't have such a meaning.